# Is it a healthy habit to walk after having food?

Tags: nutrition, physical-fitness

Particularly after lunch, I feel a bit sleepy and I love to take a nap. But many of my friends insist that I take a bit of a walk after my lunch. They recommend it as a healthy habit that helps with digestion.

Is it true? Could anyone point me to some sources that prove or disprove this?

Comment: **Please Note**. References are not optional on answers on this site. Answers which are not fact based may well be deleted even if up voted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **a walk after my lunch [is] a healthy habit that helps with digestion.**

Walking may be a healthy habit but it does not specifically assist digestion.

> Digestion is a process which takes place in resting conditions. Exercise is characterised by a shift in blood flow away from the gastrointestinal (GI) tract towards the active muscle and the lungs.

From: [Is the gut an athletic organ? Digestion, absorption, and exercise. [Sports Med. 1993] - PubMed - NCBI](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8460288)

Comment: This answer pertaining to the redirection of blood away from the stomach/GI is most important in documenting the anti-digestive action of movement.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! I think now I can take a nap after food without any guilt. :--)